# jib and AWS ECR Error uploading image to repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gradle, jib

Hi I am using github pipeline to build image using jib and upload to AWS ECR. I keep running into errors.

**AWS Settings**
I have the env variables set correctly for AWS, and using command below in github actions step I can login successfully and list images

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <repo-url>
```

My build.gradle looks like as follows for Jib

```
jib {
var tag2 = "latest"
var snapshotImageUcrUri = "xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/yyy/demo-image-0.0.1-snapshot"

from {
    image = "docker.io://amazoncorretto:17"
}
to {
    image = "$snapshotImageUcrUri"
    tags = [tag2]
}
container {
    jvmFlags = ['-Xms512m', '-Xdebug']
    mainClass = 'com.example.demo.DemoApplication'
    ports = ['9000', '9001']
    labels = [version: "0.0.1-snapshot"]
}
```

}

When running the command below I continue to see issue that it fails to upload the chunks to repo. That said I do see that it has pickedup needed creds from docker config

```
./gradlew jib

Using credentials from Docker config (/home/runner/.docker/config.json) for xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/yyy/demo-image-0.0.1-snapshot
E
```

**POST Error**

```
POST https://xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/yyy/demo-image-0.0.1-snapshot/blobs/uploads/ failed and will be retried
```

Finally it ends up here

```
I/O error for image [xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/yyy/demo-image-0.0.1-snapshot]:

    org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
    The target server failed to respond
```

Comment: This is using github actions pipeline to build and push docker image to AWS ECR

Comment: At least it is clear that authentication succeeded. As to why the AWS registry gives no HTTP response (apparently), I have no idea at all, sorry.

Comment: I have this problem even now. Did you get a workaround @user959671

Comment: Yes the way to solve is to 
1. upload to local docker
2. From local docker push to AWS ECR

`./gradlew -q jiDockerBuild --refresh-dependencies`

Then use AWS CLI to login into your ECR, tag your image and perform docker push 

`docker push "<name of latest image>"`